# Commit and Push a new package to github

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

Usually when i'm adding a new file to the repository i just right click on the file name and click commit & push.

But when i'm adding a new package,  for some reason its not working.

I tried to "add to index" the package and the file ,  but still nothing changed.
As you can see, the `_dfs` package is faded.

[image]

Comment: Check your `.gitignores`. The pattern `_*` is often ignored.

Comment: my  .gitignores is :=  /bin/
/src/

Comment: What does `git status --ignored` say?

Comment: bin/
        src/bfs/nn.java
        src/dfs/
        src/dijkastra/

Comment: dfs,dijkastra is the new packages that i added and want to commit !

Comment: OK - the solution was to  use " git add -f .\src\dijkastra\" for each new folder .- Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is add all patterns I don't want to track into `.gitignore` and then run:

```
git add --all
```

This will add all the files in your project root BUT the ones which pattern match the patterns in `.gitignore`

In case you need to untrack files without removing them from your file system (in case you miss any pattern in your .gitignore) you can use:

For files

```
git rm --cached foldername/filename
```

For folders

```
git rm --cached -r foldername
```

commit and push

```
git commit -am "Your commit message"
git push <remote_name> <branch_name>
```

Hope this helps!